# Regex to remove/replace characters before and after string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I would like to do this kind of mass replace:

From:

```
[tab=TEXT TO KEEP]
```

To:

```
[b]TEXT TO KEEP[/b]
```

Is it achievable? If too complicated, I would also be happy even without the `[B][/B]` tags.

Please note that `[tab=TEXT TO KEEP]` are included within blocks of text, so the "search" would need to start at `[tab=` stop at the first `]`.

I tried for over a hour searching tutorials but I couldn't come up with the right regex. Thank you so much to anyone who can help me with this!

Comment: Are there many underscores to replace with spaces?

Comment: No sorry that's just a typo. I mean that the text inside [tab= ] is variable. I'll fix the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following with the regular expression Search&Replace of Notepad++:

```
\[tab=([^\]]+)\]
```

Replace with:

```
[b]$1[/b]
```

`([^\]]+)` is a capture group and will match any character except closing square brackets. The captured part is stored in the first variable since it's the first capture group, hence `$1`

Comment: In my version of Notepad++ (5.9.3), I have to use `\1` as the reference to the capture group.  So, replace with `[b]\1[/b]`

Comment: @amitparikh Yes, it will depend on the version for the replace variable. v6.X are already out and widespread though, but you did right to mention it.